# Opensearch-project/oui how can I convert my lucene query to a query json in javascript

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

So, I have a search bar in which User can enter lucene query string to search / filter records.
This was working until we encounter the advanced nested structures

```
{field: [{"name": "anonymous"}]}
```

I am not able to apply filter on these type of structures.
To overcome this I came across **@opensearch-project/oui** github repo and the OuiSearchBar component. but I think I am not able to correctly use it.

Can someone suggest me how to use it properly,
Everytime I try to form ESQuery from this component I am getting a basic structure containing my query inside **query_string** Object.